# How to break out of loop when case is selected

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, case

I have a code that has 4 cases and I am trying to break the loop and if the 'f' case is chosen. and then choose from that case.  When i try to do the if statement with the break over 30 errors but when I take it away the code is fine.

```
String one = "";
boolean yea = true;   
Scanner sw = new Scanner(System.in);
while (yea == true)
{
    System.out.print(MENU);
    one  = sw.next();
    char choice  = one.charAt(0);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'f':
            friendsList();
            break; 
        case 'w':
            wall();
            break;
        case 'p':
            network();
            break;

        case 'q' : 
            yea = false;
            break; 
        default:
            System.out.println("Error: You have entered " + choice + 
            ". Please try again");

    }
}
if (case == 'f')
    {
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one, the curly braces don't match up, but why don't you post your error message?

Comment: I think the if statement to break out of the while loop needs to be inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a Java [`label`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (see this code example named [BreakWithLabelDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BreakWithLabelDemo.java)) to tell your code where to `break`.

```
myloop:
    while ( true ){
        switch( choice ){
            case 'f':
                friendsList();
                break myloop;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A link might be helpful to an API or an example

Comment: Sorry, I submitted it before I pasted in my code example

Answer (score 1):

For your implementation, it would make sense to break on a specific case before even entering the switch statement.  For example:

```
char choice  = one.charAt(0);

if (choice == 'f') break;

switch(choice)
```

This seems to be a pretty simple way to exit the while loop without conflicting with the break statements of the switch statement.

Or if you still need to call the friendsList method when `choice` is `'f'` you can move that if statement to after the switch statement.

**Note:** With this you should also remove the if statement at the bottom of your code example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (case == 'f')
```

What is case in this statement? You should replace that with choice.

```
if (choice == 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put if inside while loop.

```
    String one = "";
    boolean yea = true;   
    Scanner sw = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (yea == true)
    {
        System.out.print(MENU);
        one  = sw.next();
        char choice  = one.charAt(0);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'f':
                friendsList();
                break;
            case 'w':
                wall();
                break;
            case 'p':
                network();
                break;

            case 'q' : 
                yea = false;
                break; 
            default:
                System.out.println("Error: You have entered " + choice + 
                ". Please try again");

        }
        if (choice == 'f')
        {
        break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement should be moved inside of the while loop to be effective, and case inside the if statement should be changed to choice.

so

```
  While(yea==true)
  {
        System.out.print(MENU);
        one  = sw.next();
        char choice  = one.charAt(0);

        if(choice == 'F')
        {
              break;
        }
        switch(choice)
        {
          //cases          
        }
}
```